# Javascript: function to open the hamburger menu + header hide on scroll down and show on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, responsive

I'm trying to extract from a JS bundle not in use anymore the function I need to open the hamburger menu. The header should also hide on scroll down and show on scroll up, on desktop and mobile.

Here's what I've done so far, but I can't get JS to work. I'm still trying to understand JS, so please bear with me. Thanks.

```js
function(t, e, i) {
   "use strict";
   Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
       value: !0
   }), e.default = function() {
       var t = $("nav"),
           e = t.find(".nav-toggle"),
           i = t.offset().top + t.outerHeight() + 30,
           n = !1,
           o = !1,
           s = 0;
       $(window).on("scroll load", function() {
           var e = window.scrollY;
           e > i && !n ? (n = !0, $(t).addClass("nav-fixed")) : e < i && n && (n = !1, $(t).removeClass("nav-fixed")), e > s && !o ? (o = !0, $(t).addClass("nav-hidden"), $(t).removeClass("nav-shown")) : e < s && o && (o = !1, $(t).addClass("nav-shown"), $(t).removeClass("nav-hidden")), s = e
       }), e.click(function() {
           if ($(t).toggleClass("nav-active"), $("body").toggleClass("stopScroll"), t.hasClass("nav-active")) $(t).find(".nav-list li").each(function(t, e) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $(e).find("a").addClass("fade")
               }, 100 * t + 100)
           });
           else {
               var e = $(t).find(".nav-list li");
               $(e).find("a").removeClass("fade")
           }
       })
   }
};
```

```css
.header .nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 10
}

.header .nav-brand {
    z-index: 2
}

@media (max-width:1024px) {
    .header .nav-brand img {
        max-width: 240px
    }
}

.header .nav-toggle {
    width: 25px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
    .header .nav-toggle {
        display: none
    }
}

.header .nav-toggle-bar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    transition: transform .1s ease
}

.header .nav-toggle-bar:first-of-type {
    top: 0;
    width: 25px
}

.header .nav-toggle-bar:last-of-type {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 25px
}

.header .nav-wrap {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center
}

.header .nav-list {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    transition: left .3s cubic-bezier(.895, .03, .685, .22);
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 160px 0 0 7.5%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    z-index: 1
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
    .header .nav-list {
        display: block;
        position: static;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        padding: 0
    }
}

.header .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 60px
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {
    .header .nav li.current-page a {
        position: relative
    }

    .header .nav li.current-page a:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #fff
    }
}

.header .nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0
}

@media (min-width:1025px) {

    .header .nav li a {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity .1s linear
    }

    .header .nav li a:hover {
        opacity: .6
    }
}

.header .nav li:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0
}

.header .nav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 30px 0 22px;
    background-color: #131313
}

.header .nav-fixed.nav-hidden {
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%)
}

.header .nav-fixed.nav-shown {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: transform .2s ease-in
}

.header .nav-active .nav-toggle-bar {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.header .nav-active .nav-toggle-bar:first-of-type {
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg)
}

.header .nav-active .nav-toggle-bar:last-of-type {
    width: 25px;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg)
}

.header .nav-active .nav-list {
    left: 0
}

.header .nav-active .nav-list a.fade {
    animation: fadeInLeft;
    animation-duration: .4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
```

```html
<body>

<header class="header">
    <nav class="nav nav-hidden">
        <div class="container nav-wrap">
            <div class="nav-brand">
                                <a href="index.html" aria-label="Back Home"><img src="logo.svg" alt=""></a>
            </div>
<ul class="nav-list">
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul>            <div class="nav-toggle">
                <span class="nav-toggle-bar"></span>
                <span class="nav-toggle-bar"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: It's incredibly hard to comprehend what the code is doing when it is minified. Are you able to share the code in its original form?

Comment: You mean the complete JS bundle? It's more than 400 KB. I don't know if I can publish it here. Can I?

Comment: No, not the complete bundle. But if I understand correctly you are trying to get a piece of functionality from a bundled piece of code but can't get the separated code to work on its own? Even for an experienced developer this is a hard task when the code looks like this. What's the reason you're trying it this way?

Comment: The part that you're currently trying to extract has gone through some build steps, which makes it very difficult to use and read. There should be a file (or multiple files) that contain the *raw* version of the code, before going through the build steps. If possible, use that to extract your code. Also leave a link in your question to the code you're trying to use.

Comment: Yes Emiel, exactly, that's what I'm trying. And I'm not even a JS developer. I was trying to get this piece of code to work, but it's beyond my abilities. I suspected there was something else in the bundle that affects the function I'm trying to recreate, but obviously I can't find what it is. Maybe I will try to extract it with Chrome Coverage and Puppeteer, first by stripping out everything but the navigation in the html. Of course, first I must learn how to properly run Puppeteer.